# Do both the criteria 'seconds' & 'key modification' have to be met for Snapshotting to work - Redis

Tags: redis

I have setup snapshotting in redis -:

```
save 900 1
save 60 10000
```

Now i am confused here. Do both the criteria `seconds` & `key modification` have to be met for Redis to snapshot. If this is the case, during the server crash my data would be lost if the time hasn't reached 60 seconds.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

With that setting Redis will dump the dataset to disk every 60 seconds if at least 10000 keys changed, or every 900 if at least 1 key changed

redis persistency is well explained by redis author here: http://redis.io/topics/persistence